# ATL COM out-of-proc server in existing exe

Tags: c++, com, atl, out-of-process

I already have an existing code of my application. And i want to create a COM server, which will work inside that process. And this application process will be like a COM server. It is possible to realize using ATL? Maybe someone knows examples of realization?

Comment: What does an out of process server in another process actually mean? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have an application process which will be like com server. And i have a client process, which will make requests to server and server will send data.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You have a process/application and you want COM server to serve external requests? Why? Why inside existing process? Use cases? Why ATL?

Comment: Because this process has some "context", like access to db or other application data, which i need to process client requirements. For example: i have a browser plugin (com client), which must show some data from application process (com server), and server have "context" needed to client.

Comment: Why ATL? Because clean COM server is deprecated and it is more correct to use ATL. Am i right?

Comment: Clean COM is alive and doing well. ATL is a relatively easy way to do COM in C++. You can `RegisterActiveObject` from the process with context, and other processes would obtain a marshaled COM interface via `GetActiveObject` and communicate to your server. Yes, you can do it with ATL.

Comment: It's very clear what he wants.